# Iceweasel: Change default/home page via command line

Tags: iceweasel

I'd like to change the home/default page (which is shown at startup).
I know how to change it in the iceweasel GUI (preferences), but I'd like to change it remotely via SSH.

Is there a config file which contains the default page?

EDIT: 
I need it as stored configuration, so that on every reboot the configured page is shown

Comment: ...`ssh -X Boardwish@remotecomputer  ` then `iceweasel -no-remote`... if you do not find another solution :-) it will be slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The home page is defined by the `browser.startup.homepage` preference.

Before Firefox is used the first time, this can be defined in a file in the default preferences, e.g. `/usr/share/iceweasel/browser/defaults/preferences/` on Debian or `/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/` on Fedora. There should already be a `.js` file there; replace `prefs("browser.startup.homepage", "...");` in that file with the value you want, or add a new line if there is no such line already.

Once Firefox has been used once, the value is defined in the user profile's `prefs.js` file, e.g. in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profile.default/prefs.js` (replacing `profile` with the appropriate value), in the same way as above. (There may be other profiles alongside the default one.)